# How do you run an Android Wearable app?

Tags: android, wear-os

This may be a silly question.

I've followed [the instructions](http://developer.android.com/training/building-wearables.html) to create and Android Wearable app.  I can compile and run it in a Wearable emulator.  Everything is great.

What I can't figure out is: how do I run my app?  I can run it fine from Android Studio, but there doesn't seem to be any sort of interface on the Wearable emulator to find and launch apps.

Is there an equivalent to the Android phone Launcher but for Wearables?  And if not, how do I run a wearable app from the wearable emulator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully I don't get your question wrong, but here's how you can start any app installed on the wearable:

#### 1 - Click anywhere on your WatchFace screen

[image: WatchFace]

#### 2 - Scroll all the way down and tap on "Start..."

[image: Options drawer]

#### 3 - There you see all of the apps

[image: App drawer]

**Note:** You have to consider that Google "hid" this, let's call it, "Launcher-Menu" for good reasons. (At least Google thinks so). That's because you can start nearly any app via a Voice-Command like *"Ok Google, Start XYZ"*. (Which won't work on an emulator of course)
And for everyone who's not cool with that there're also [Third-Party apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.npi.wearminilauncher&hl=de) which let you start an "App Drawer" right from the WatchFace [(click)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.npi.wearminilauncher&hl=de).

Answer (score 0):

Below is a link with instructions on how to get an emulator up and running for testing purposes. I'm pretty sure this answers your question.

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html

Let me know if this helps you or not

Comment: What specifically is your answer?